# Python list comprehension with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

Can someone please explain to me

1. Why `a` is a list of True/False, while `b` is a list of lambdas?
2. Why does the rule does not apply to `c` and `d`?

Codes:

```
foo = (lambda a, b: a >= b) if False else (lambda a, b: a <= b)
a = [foo(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]

foo = lambda a, b: a >= b if False else lambda a, b: a <= b
b = [foo(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]

bar = (lambda a, b: a*b*10) if False else (lambda a, b: a*b*100)
c = [bar(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]

bar = lambda a, b: a*b*10 if False else lambda a, b: a*b*100
d = [bar(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In this expression, `foo = lambda a, b: a >= b if descending else lambda a, b: a <= b` there is no delimeter indicating the end of the lambda, so the if-else is _inside_ the lambda. If descending is false, the else runs, and the outer lambda returns `lambda a, b: a <= b`.

Comment: Made a mistake, all keywords `descending` has been replaced with `True`. Thanks @BlackBear, @Joran Beasley

Comment: (b) is no longer a list of lambdas if you replace it with True

Comment: Thank you guys, now I understand why. As a question, I now changed all True to False for other people's benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = lambda a, b: a >= b if descending else lambda a, b: a <= b
b = [foo(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]
```

can be rewritten as

```
foo = lambda a, b:  (a >= b if descending else lambda a, b: a <= b)
b = [foo(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]
```

which if it is descending is fine as LHS is evaluated to

```
foo = lambda a,b: a >= b  #does what you would expet
```

but if its not you get

```
foo = lambda a,b: lambda a,b:a<=b
```

which clearly returns a lambda not a value

you could change it to

```
foo = lambda a, b: a >= b if descending else  a <= b
b = [foo(x, x+1) for x in xrange(10)]
```

and it should work as you expect

Answer (score 4):

It is just a matter of operator precedence. Let's put some brackets to show how the statements are parsed:

```
(a) foo = (lambda a, b: a >= b) if True else (lambda a, b: a <= b)
(b) foo = lambda a, b: (a >= b if descending else lambda a, b: a <= b)
```

When evaluating (b) descending happens to be false, so all the elements become `lambda a, b: a <= b`